# Dataset Does Not Contain a Definition for Rows

Tags: c#, dataset

```
DataSet dtCategory= Database.GetCategory();
string colValues = (from DataRow row in dtCategory.Rows select row["ColumnName"]).ToList();
```

I am facing the error of having `.Rows` being underlined in red saying the following:

> Dataset does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no accessible
>   extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'DataSet'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

May I know what should I change? Thank you.

Comment: A `DataSet` has a property `DataTable` (an array) which has a `Rows` property. Use `DataSet.DataTable[0].Rows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the concept of DataTable, DataTable, and DataRow. DataSet is a collection of DataTables, you can find the DataRows inside the DataTable only. so you have to get the tables first to access the rows inside the table.

You have to make a few more corrections to make your code works:

- You have declared the variable `colValues` as a string and you are assigning a List() to it. Which will raise compilation issues. Better option is to change the destination type as `List<string>`.
- Instead of accessing row values using column name alone, make use of the corresponding type as well. like `row.Field<string>("ColumnName")`
- Check for the existence of a table in the Dataset for a safer side.

The final code will be looks like the following:

```
if (dtCategory != null && dtCategory.Tables.Count > 0) 
{
    List<string> colValues = (from DataRow row in dtCategory.Tables[0].Rows select row.Field<string>("ColumnName")).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Rows is not a DataRow type.It is DataRowCollection type. We have to cast the code then only it will be get it as DataRow. Would you try the below code.

 var rows = (from row in dt.Rows.Cast()
                        select row["columnName"]);